# Can I delegatecall my own internal function?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I have a contract that uses

```
address(this).delegatecall(...)
```

Can I put an internal function inside the delegatecall somehow?
I tried the normal way, public functions worked but internal didn't. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible because internal function do not have an entry point in the contract function dispatcher. The whole point of internal function is that they are not callable from outside the contract.

You can call a public function and make that function call the internal function.

Comment: but I'm not calling it outside the contract, is there no inner entry point maybe?

Comment: @egjlmn1 Using delegatecall is an external call.